# Helm subchart pre-upgrade hooks run every time the umbrella chart is upgraded

Tags: kubernetes, hook, kubernetes-helm

I have an umbrella helm chart which has subcharts. Some of the subcharts have pre-install/pre-upgrade hooks (jobs).
Every time I run `helm upgrade <release name> <umbrella chart>` the pre-upgrade hooks of all subcharts are executed, even if there are no changes in corresponding subcharts.

Is this expected behavior? And is there a possibility to run subchart hooks only in case when there are changes in subchart?

UPD: more details

So this is the chart structure:

```
parent_chart/
├─ charts/
│  ├─ child_chart_1/
│  │  ├─ templates/
│  │  │  ├─ hooks_1.yaml
│  │  │  ├─ deployment_1.yaml
│  │  ├─ Chart.yaml
│  │  ├─ values.yaml
│  ├─ child_chart_2/
│  │  ├─ templates/
│  │  │  ├─ deployment_2.yaml
│  │  │  ├─ hooks_2.yaml
│  │  ├─ Chart.yaml
│  │  ├─ values.yaml
├─ values.yaml
├─ Chart.yaml
```

hook manifest looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-migration-hook
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    helm.sh/chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install, pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
spec:
  ...
```

Let's assume this chart is installed.
Then I do changes in `child_chart_1/values.yaml` and upgrade the umbrella chart:

```
helm upgrade release_name parent_chart
```

During the upgrade hooks from both `hooks_1.yaml` and `hooks_2.yaml` are executed, but I need only `hooks_1.yaml` to run, because there are no changes in `child_chart_2`.

Comment: could you please provide the logs and more details?

Comment: hi, added some more details. What kind of logs do you need ?

Comment: hi, @Arsen, I need your values.yaml file and hooks yamls to able to reproduce your issue

Comment: Here's the packaged chart:  https://gist.github.com/arsssen/5353257ab9e84f6b6dc62d26106e3e68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the annotation `checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}` to avoid the executing the child chart that was not updated. So if the spec is not changed, then the application keeps running with the old configuration resulting in an inconsistent deployment.

For more information please refer to this  ['Chart Development Tips and Tricks' article](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments)

---

### UPDATE

Then it's expected behaviour. What's your Helm version? Since it's was totally expected behaviour in Helm 2 and there is a [Issue in GitHub](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8361) with similar problem as yours.

Also we can see the [resolution comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8361#issuecomment-677961435) that's explaining of [New 3-way Strategic Merge Patches](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/changes_since_helm2/#improved-upgrade-strategy-3-way-strategic-merge-patches) that should resolve this issue somehow, but in their examples I can't see that it was fixed with the annotation `pre-upgrade`. Fell free to open that issue and ping them.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. The child chart is not updated with or without this annotation, but the hooks always run.

Comment: hi @Arsen, I've edited my answer with an additional information

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.
All the pre-upgrade, post-upgrade jobs runs every time. Even if I just run `helm upgrade` without any change, it will trigger the jobs to run.
Previously in helm2, it doesn't run unless I bump up the version of the subcharts that have the pre-upgrade/post-upgrade hooks